# losgtash grok pattern error with custom log

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I'm new with ELK stack. I need to parse my customlogs using Grok and then analyze them.

```
[11/Oct/2018 09:51:47] INFO [serviceManager.management.commands.serviceManagerMonitor:serviceManagerMonitor.py:114] [2018-10-11 07:51:47.527997+00:00] SmMonitoring Module : Launching action info over the service sysstat is delayed
```

with this grok pattern:

```
\[(?<timestamp>%{MONTHDAY}\/%{MONTH}\/%{YEAR} %{TIME})\] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} \[%{GREEDYDATA:messagel}\] \[%{GREEDYDATA:message2}\] %{GREEDYDATA:message3}
```

i tried a grok debugger and it's matched
here is the configuration of logstash for the input:

```
input {
 beats {
 port => 5044
  }
}
```

and here is the output configuration:

```
output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
sniffing => true
manage_template => false
index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
}
}
```

and here is the whole filter:

```
filter {

        grok {
          match => { "message" => "\[(?<timestamp>%{MONTHDAY}\/%{MONTH}\/%{YEAR} %{TIME})\] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} \[%{GREEDYDATA:messagel}\] \[%{GREEDYDATA:message2}\] %{GREEDYDATA:message3}" }
        }
      date {
        match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
      }
    }
```

but i don't get any result with elasticsearch.
Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Your grok patterns seems correct, so the issue might be with the rest of you configuration. Edit your question with your configuration or ask a new question.

Comment: So the rest of the configuration is good. If you are running logstash from the command line, what's the output? Are you sure filebeat is sending anything (filebeat remembers what it has already read and won't read it again)? One easy way to check what logstash is receiving is to add a stdout output, so that way you have a way to know what's happening.

Comment: i found the problem, filebeat cannot make a connection with logstash
`Failed to connect to backoff(async(tcp://127.0.0.1:5044)): dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5044: connect: connection refused`